# Allow PHP in textarea

Tags: php

How Can I allow php script in textarea. I know its risky by security means but I want to do it through admin panel so no worries about security.
I want to include 1 php file in textarea and want to execute it when i display textarea content.
How can I do it?

Comment: this is wrong in so many levels... buuut if you really want to do it.. why not upload the file instead of pasting it to a textarea, copy it to a dir where apache has execute rights, chmod to 700 and execute it using shell_exec?

Comment: Let me explain my scenario.
I have built a CMS, where in some new posts I need a dynamic code (Which i have on separate file) to run on a certain position on that post.
Hope you understand

Comment: Check out [`Reflection`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). A clever use of the `ReflectionClass` can do this for you with some ability to do it safely.

Comment: While you say you understand the risks, I'd still recommend, don't. Just don't. Even if it is in an "admin panel", that doesn't limit the risk by much. Don't complain when somebody manages to brick the server / your database.

Comment: @Jon Striling
Then kindly recommend the way I can achieve what I want to do

Comment: I want something like in wordpress, "Allow PHP in Posts and Pages" Plugin

Comment: @nandla Why not just use Wordpress then?

Comment: @phpisuber01 - Could you expand on how the ReflectionClass could help with this?

Comment: @Jon Stirling I dont wana use wordpress due to several reasons here

Comment: @Matt Basically you create a class, with methods and build in some security on the fly with your code from the text area in a method or property. Then use Reflection Class to instantiate the code and run your methods. Reflection allows you to take code from a string and execute it at runtime as if it were inline with your document, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Save the corresponding PHP code to a new file and then simply include the PHP file at the position where you want to show it.

Comment: You should probably have two text areas. One with regular text and a placeholder where you want to insert PHP and then a second one with PHP input. You save the PHP one to a text file (or database) and then when you echo the first text area at the placeholder you include the file.

Comment: Positions are different for each file. So I can't fix positions

Answer (score 0):

Get the code you wanna run into a string variable.

eval($phpcode);

Why do you want so much to run that file code in that specific place? Can't the code be put into a function and you call the function there?

Also, explain what exactally is happening. What's this dynamic PHP code that needs to be run? You're giving, to code you have no control, full acess to your environment, including your DB and passwords stored in PHP files! If by a simple GET parameter, ppl can stack overflow and get full control of a site, you're giving them full easy control over everything! And don't tell us it's in admin panel, if you think that's enough to have security, bigger the security flaw is!

Even if it's a hundred possible codes. Put them into a file inside functions and provide user a list of comboboxes to choose which to run.

If admin user needs to custom some code, use a plugin system.

If admin user really needs to run custom quick code, give him access to your control panel so that he can add and edit files directly.

Comment: How Can I Allow this in textarea? Sorry If I have messed up

Comment: Let me explain my scenario.
I've a CMS, I want to include a file which fetches some live updates say from twitter, That file which need to included here is changing its GET variable only. But I can't fix its position where I can include that file, That can be included above first para, below 2nd para, after 2nd heading and can not be added as well.

Comment: then put its position in a database and retreive it. you don't need to run a php code for such simple things.

Answer (score 0):

you can use on server side the [eval](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php) function, but before use need clean the php tags.

```
<form method="post" action="server.php">
    <textarea name="text_area"></textarea>
</form>

<?php
// when display content
$pattern = "/<\?php(.*?)\?>/";
preg_match($pattern, $textarea_value, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $phpcode) {
    eval($phpcode);
}
?>
```

of course don't forget about security reason.
this code allow to add in textarea many php code and simple text same time

Comment: $textarea_value is text from textarea, you get it from DB or other location where you save it (sorry my bad english :) )

Comment: Not Working, empty result :(

Answer (score 0):

I understand you wanna receive text typed in a textarea, or run some code inside a textarea element...

```
<?php
    $unsecurePHPcode = $POST['unsecurePHPcode'];
?>
<textarea name="unsecurePHPcode">
<?php eval($unsecurePHPcode); ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Parse error:  parse error in C:\wamp\www\xxxxxxxx\try.php(6) : eval()'d code on line 2